# Horizontal list view item click event is not performing on same position in Android

Tags: android

The Adapter for horizontal list view is below. When I click on the list item view then to hide it the other list item position is hiding.

```
// get view method and  item row inflating
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder() ;
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewitem, null) ;
        holder.rootLayout       = (LinearLayout)    convertView.findViewById(R.id.animation_root_layout) ;
        holder.frontLayout      = (LinearLayout)    convertView.findViewById(R.id.ticket_front_layout) ;
        holder.backLayout       = (LinearLayout)    convertView.findViewById(R.id.ticket_back_layout) ;
        holder.backLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.passDetails      = (TextView)        convertView.findViewById(R.id.passenger_details_button) ;
        holder.ticketDetails    = (TextView)        convertView.findViewById(R.id.ticket_details_button) ;

        holder.passDetails.setTag(position); // set the tag to item
        holder.ticketDetails.setTag(position);
        holder.frontLayout.setTag(position);
        holder.backLayout.setTag(position);
        convertView.setTag(R.layout.viewitem,holder); // set the tag to view

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag(R.layout.viewitem) ;
    }

    holder.passDetails.setText("P Details : "+position);
    holder.ticketDetails.setText("T Details : "+position);
    // setting click listener on list item that is a linear layout
    holder.passDetails.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int which = -1;
            Object obj =  v.getTag();
            if(obj instanceof Integer) {
                which  = ((Integer)obj).intValue();
            }

            if(which >-1){
                // on click visibility view or gone

                holder.frontLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.backLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
        }
    });
    // setting click listener on list item that is a linear layout second
    holder.ticketDetails.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (customListner != null) {
                int which = -1;
                Object obj =  v.getTag();
                if(obj instanceof Integer) {
                    which  = ((Integer)obj).intValue();
                }    
                if(which >-1) {
                    holder.frontLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.backLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE); 

                }

            }
        }
    });
    return convertView ;
}

// view holder for the list variables
public class ViewHolder {
    ImageView refresh, share ;
    TextView passDetails, ticketDetails ;
    LinearLayout frontLayout , backLayout, rootLayout ;
}
```

In the above code when I click on the horizontal list item to hide it , it hides the other item position. How do I hide the exact position only in horizontal list item click

This is the layout xml file (viewitem.xml) : 
In this I have row item layout and this contain two linear layout first one is visibility visible and second one visibility gone.

I want to make the second linear layout visible on click of an item programmatically from adapter and hide the first layout.

but the problem I am facing is when I click on the item of list view first one visibility is gone but Second layout not visible.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/animation_root_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ticket_front_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       >


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:text="parvindra"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/passenger_details_button"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ticket_back_layout"

      >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:text="singh"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/ticket_details_button"/>

        </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you add image of your layout?

Comment: Hi latheef thanks for reply.  I have edited the question with my layout xml also. can you check this. Thanks